# css style for add some space before text

Tags: php, html, css

I want to add some space before the text which is in 'content' div tag.
Now all my text are stick to left side.all text in content are sticked into left.
I added margin-left style for p tag. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lrh19c50/)

I tried

```
margin-left:10px;
```

But till having problem.

```css
.sidemenu {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 150px;
  width: 100%;
   }
.content {
  
 
  }
 hr {
      margin: 0;
      width: 1px;
      height: 660px;
      border: 0;
      background: #fff;
      float: left;
    }
.side{
  width: 24%;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
 .rest {
  height: 685px;
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #e5e3e3 5%, #ffffff 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #e5e3e3), color-stop(1, #ffffff));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #e5e3e3 5%, #ffffff 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#e5e3e3", endColorstr="#ffffff");
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #e5e3e3, ffffff);
  background-color: #e5e3e3;
  border: 1px solid #f9f2f2;
  border-width: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
  padding: 0px 7px;
}
.outer {
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-top: 3%;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
  height: 737px;
  width: 60%;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
  border: 1px solid #f9f2f2;
  border-radius: 10px;
  
}
 p{
      margin-left:100px;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="outer">
                <div class="log">
                <h1>Profile</h1>
                       <form method="post" class="lout" > <button class="logout" name="logout" >Logout</button></form>
                       
                </div> <!--End of log div -->
                <div class="rest">
                  <div class="side">
                   <div class="sidemenu">
                        <div class="1 menu">
                          <a href="admin_dashboard.php" class="astext">Profile</a>
                        </div> <!--End of menu1 -->
                        <div class="2 menu">
                          <a href="clients.php" class="astext">Clients</a>
                        </div> <!--End of menu 2-->
                        <div class="3 menu">
                          <a href="employees.php" class="astext">Employees</a>
                        </div> <!--End of menu 3-->
                        <div class="menu 4">
                        <a href="admin_file_view.php" class="astext">Documents</a>
                        </div> <!--End of menu 4-->
                   </div> <!--End of side menu -->
                   </div>  <!--End of side div -->
                   <hr>
                    <!--  <div class="heading" >
                         <h1>Profile</h1>
                      </div>    End of heading div -->
                   <div class="content">
                       <?php
       include "config.php";
       if($ses!='')
       {
        $sql="select * from register where id=$ses";
        $sql1=mysql_query($sql);
        $fet=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1);
        $name=$fet['name'];
        $email=$fet['email'];
        $phone=$fet['phone'];
        $cname=$fet['company_name'];
        $street=$fet['street'];
        $add=$fet['address'];
        $city=$fet['city'];
        $state=$fet['state'];
        $ein=$fet['ein'];
        $id=$fet['id'];
       }
      ?>
      <form name="profile" method="post">
   
   
    <p>Name<input type="text" size=20 maxlength=50 style="background-color:transparent;border:0px solid white;" readonly value="<?php echo $name; ?>"</p>
    <p>Email<input type="text" size=20 name="mail" maxlength=50 style="background-color:transparent;border:0px solid white;" readonly value="<?php echo $email; ?>"</p>
    <p>Phone<input type="text" size=20 maxlength=50 style="background-color:transparent;border:0px solid white;" readonly value="<?php echo $phone; ?>"></p>
    <p>Company name<input type="text" size=20 maxlength=50 style="background-color:transparent;border:0px solid white;" readonly value="<?php echo $cname;?>"></p>
           <p>Street<input type="text" size=20 maxlength=50 style="background-color:transparent;border:0px solid white;" readonly value="<?php echo $street;?>"></p>
    <p>Address<input type="text" size=20 maxlength=50 style="background-color:transparent;border:0px solid white;" readonly value="<?php echo $add; ?>"></p>
    <p>City<input type="text" size=20 maxlength=50 style="background-color:transparent;border:0px solid white;" readonly value="<?php echo $city;?>"></p>
    <p>State<input type="text" size=20 maxlength=50 style="background-color:transparent;border:0px solid white;" readonly value="<?php echo $state; ?>"></p>
    <p>EIN<input type="text" size=20 maxlength=50 style="background-color:transparent;border:0px solid white;" readonly value="<?php echo $ein;?>"></p>
   <a class="change">Change Password</a><br>
    <div class="pass">
       <br><input type="password" class="textbox" placeholder="Current Password" name="old" id="old" size="20"/><br><br>
                        <input type="password"  class="textbox" placeholder="New Password" name="new" id="new" size="20"><br>
                       <br><br><br><br><button class="add" name="go" id="go">Go</button><a style="padding-right:2ex;"></a><a class="change"><button class="add" name="cancel" id="cancel">Cancel</button></a>
    </div> 
    <br>
    <div class="tri"><button name="edit" class=add>&nbsp&nbspEdit&nbsp</button><button name="add"  class="upload" onclick="admin()">Add New</button></div></form>
     
    
   
                   </div> <!--End of content -->
                </div> <!--End of rest div -->
          </div> <!--End of outer div-->
```

Answer (score 1):

you can see the demo here 
[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lrh19c50/2/)

i have made change in `form{padding-left:31%;}`

### Try the new with top margin

[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lrh19c50/3/)

in this i modified `.rest{margin-top:15%;}`

Comment: I want to add some space above.please note name is hidden

Comment: thismake changed in log div tag style.please note it.

Comment: i can not see where you tell send me screenshot for better understanding

Comment: in chat you can upload it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72456/discussion-between-user3386779-and-priya786).

Answer (score 0):

see demo i can add some css

http://jsfiddle.net/Lrh19c50/1/

```
form[name=profile] p{
padding-left:30%;
}
```

Comment: I need to add some space above the text content.

Answer (score 0):

You want to add some spaces to a `div` into content class, so you can use `.content div` as a css selector. That means each `div` under content class, you can give padding as you want.

```
.content div { padding-left : 30px; }
```

Comment: Could you please specify a bit more about your answer? It's generally appreciated if you explain a little about your answer.

Comment: You want add some spaces to div into content class. so you can use .content div as css selector. it means each div under content class. and you can give padding as you want.